# Django - How to delete an entry from model by user?

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4, django-views

I am new in Django framework. And I am developing a web app. In this app I have a list of entries like (Title and description). I have add one more column that contains a delete button. I want when someone click on that button (delete button) it deletes entry. For front end I am using Bootstrap.

my `views.py`

```
from django.http import request
from .models import Task
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    context = {"success":  False}
    if request.method=='POST':
        title= request.POST['title']
        desc = request.POST['desc']
        print(title, desc)
        ins = Task(title=title, desc=desc)
        ins.save()
        context = {"success":  True}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def tasks(request):
    alltasks = Task.objects.all()
    # print(alltasks)
    # for item in alltasks:
    #     print(item.title)
    context = {'tasks': alltasks}
       
    
    return render(request, 'tasks.html', context)
```

my `urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('tasks', views.tasks, name="tasks"),
    
]
```

And my template

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Tasks</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">TODO</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item ">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/tasks">Tasks</a>
            </li>
        </div>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
    </nav>
    <h2 class="text-center py-3"> <b>Here is your Tasks</b> </h2>
    <div class="container">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">S.No.</th>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Task Title</th>
            <th scope="col">Task Description</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
            
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for task in tasks %}
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{forloop.counter}}</th>
            <td>{{task.time}}</td>
            <td>{{task.title}}</td>
            <td>{{task.desc}}</td>
            <td><button  type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button></td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
          
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <p class="text-center bg-dark text-light fixed-bottom my-0 py-2">
        Copyright &copy; 2020 | All rights reserved

      </p>
    </footer>
    

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: jQuery, Popper.js, and Bootstrap JS
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For every MODEL.method() you should give parenthesis. object.delete()

Answer (score 0):

It is `delete()` not `delete`. So:

```
def delete_view():
    object = Task.objects.get(id = part_id)
    object.delete()
    return render(request, 'tasks.html')
```

[Refs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects)

#### Note

Because your `delete` action should be somewhat secure. So it is better to use `POST` method instead of simple `GET` method. So add `POST` method in your template like:

```
...
{% for task in tasks %}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{forloop.counter}}</th>
        <td>{{task.time}}</td>
        <td>{{task.title}}</td>
        <td>{{task.desc}}</td>
        <td>
            <form action="url: delete_view"" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

And your delete_view() will delete only if the request is `POST`:

```
def delete_view():
    if request.POST:
        object = Task.objects.get(id = part_id)
        object.delete()
    return render(request, 'tasks.html')
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working. `Button` not clicked? or `object.delete()` not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django's generic class-based view

```
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView
from .models import Task
    
class DeleteTrackView(DeleteView):
    model = Task
    success_url = reverse_lazy(<task_list>)
    template_name = "<path_to_template>"
```

In template

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete "{{ object }}"?</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
</form>
```

Using generic class-based views you can avoid redundant boilerplate codes.

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview

Comment: I didn't understand success_url. What does it mean?

Comment: And it is not deleting the object

Comment: If the object is deleted successfully, the view will redirect to the URL that you put in the success_url attribute.

In your case, on clicking the delete from the list of tasks it will ask for the confirmation and then on success, you might want to redirect it back to the list of tasks.